Modifying an argument passed with this keyword to take effect outside the method
A parameter passed with the this keyword is passed as value as far as I know. However this answer explained that they are rather passed as variables.
So, is there a way to query in some way the object that the this parameter is pointing at, that can be modified inside of the method, but still affects the original object?

I want to recreate Javascript's array.push function in C#. I am aware that List.add() works the same way as array.push, but I'm not allowed to use List, just arrays.
Javascript's array.push modifies the original array and returns the new length of the array.
I did make this function to partially replicate array.push, but since array is passed as value, I could only modify the copy of the copy of the original array, that didn't take effect outside of the method. The commented out Array.Copy was an another attempt that yielded the exact same result.
public static void push<type>(this type[] array,params type[] var)
{
    Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + var.Length);
    for (int i = array.Length - var.Length, j = 0; i < array.Length; i++, j++) array[i]=var[j];
    //Array.Copy(var, 0, array, array.Length - var.Length, var.Length);
}


You can't do it with an extension method. You would need to do ref this type[] array, and ref this isn't allowed on reference types like arrays.

Side note: Follow the generic type parameter naming conventions: either T or something like TElement instead of type.

Please explain why you're not allowed to use a List; don't just tell us that you can't. If this is a school assignment, we can accept that because didactic methods often place arbitrary, non-optimal restrictions for the sake of learning. Otherwise, you need to push back. Resizing the array every time you push an item (and preusmably when you pop, too, since you're not tracking count and capacity separately) is very bad. By contrast, a List will only reallocate when you exceed the current capacity.

Indeed, this is a college assignment. I already got away with using higher level technology, but this task specifically required me to use 2 dimensional arrays.

How about not writing this as an extension method? Is writing an extension method also required by the task?

No, it's for convenience sake. I wanted to make a function that work similarly to the js one, because that works like an extension, and I'm already familiar with how that works. Otherwise since the deadline came, I just did it using ref and not using this. It's pointless to try to make this work if it's impossible in the .net framework
